# Power on/off time from command line or C

Tags: boot, power-management, rtcwake

Can I set and/or change automatic power on/off time from command line/C code?

Is it possible at least for wake up?

I want to make the PC to power on and power off every day, then adjust time points programmatically.

If my motherboard have "Power On By RTC" settings, can I change the times programmatically?

Comment: C maybe, commandline most likely not. It would require setting the timer in the bios. Once the pc is powered off, it can't be altered. Powershell might also be able to do this, but I haven't dived into it. It will indeed require the Power On by RTC setting.

Comment: @LPChip I found `rtcwake -m off ...`.